# Selector being called even when I don't mutate what its mapPropsToState

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React app that does some simple recording.  I have a Component `Recorder` which connects to my redux store like this:

```
export default connect(
    state => ({ 
        recordings: state.recordings,
        recordingSelector: selectRecordingBufferWithID(this.recordingID) 
    }), 

    dispatch =>
        bindActionCreators({ 
                startNewRecordingAction, 
                stopNewRecordingAction 
            },
            dispatch
        )
)(SampleRecorder);
```

The problem I'm having is that `selectRecordingBufferWithID` in my redux code is firing too often.  Part of my reducer code looks like this:

```
function samplesReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MORE_SAMPLES:
            return [...action.samples];
        default:
            return state
    }   
}

function recordingsReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case NEW_RECORDING:
            return newRecording(state, action.recordingID);
        case STOP_RECORDING:
            return stopRecording(state, action.recordingID);
        default:
            return state

    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    samplesReducer,
    recordingsReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
export { store };
```

So, while I want `selectRecordingBufferWithID` to be utilized only when a `START/STOP_RECORDING` action occurs, it is called for each time `MORE_SAMPLES` is called.

---

My understanding of `react-redux` is that the selector is part of the `mapStateToProps` function that the `connect` function accepts.  And somehow, `connect` cause my component to render and for its props to be updated with the mapped state from the redux store.  the `selectRecordingBufferWithID` selector will also be called each time this happens so I can do a refined getter into the store.

So to summarize, my `recordingSelector` is firing more often than I expect.  My only theory is that my reducers are somehow mutating the state of `state.recordings` each time it tries to reduce `state.samples` which makes `react-redux` render my component with it mapped to `state.recording`.

But otherwise, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect` does not work the way you think it does. What it really does is:

1. Subscribe to the store. This subscription will be triggered after **every dispatched action**.
2. Execute your mapStateToProps to inject the initial set of props to your Sample Recorder component.
3. When any action dispatches, the subscription kicks in, and connect applies again your mapStateToProps to new global state.
4. If your selector returns the same props as before, it won't render your SampleRecorder again.

So the misunderstanding is that your selector shouldn't be called. But the fact is that connect needs to call your selector to decide when to re-render and when not.

The summary of this is that your selector should be either simple, or memoizable using `reselect` to avoid expensive calculations. You didn't show you selector code so we can't tell from here. :)

Comment: ah, so i did put 2&2 together eventually and see that while the selector would be called repeatedly the component would not render on all occasions.  given the way mapStateToProps works I can certainly see the motivation for reselect/memoization but given how trivial my current selector is I'm ok with it doing the redundant computation.  so you are exactly right on what my misunderstanding was.  I thought that mapStateToProps was called under the same conditions that the component render was but it is called even if the relevant state tree part isn't changed.

Comment: Exactly, simply reading some part of the state (accessing a slice of it) is in my experience almost 0 "delay". I use reselect if I have a lot of connected components or when I'm generating new data from data in the store. i.e: mapping an array of ids to entities, so on. :)